# Does Hololens 2 use also Long throw AB / AHAT AB for SLAM?

Tags: hololens

I am curious if it is possible to improve tracking accuracy in certain environments by placing retro-reflective stickers into the environment?

Great use case for this type of setup might be in a dark environments, or in environments with dynamic lightning changes and many moving elements. In case Hololens 2 uses also Long throw AB / AHAT AB for SLAM, these retro-reflective stickers would nicely reflect infra-red light - producing very bright and stable dots in AB texture. These dots could be tracked as feature points and eventually greatly enhance SLAM accuracy in such cases.

Comment: Hololens 2 uses an Infrared depth camera and it's available for SLAM in research mode. How your IR dots work may depend on the scenario - visible tags are commonly used to help uniquify the environment. See https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/blog/microsoft-hololens-2-improved-research-mode-to-facilitate-computer-vision-research/ https://www.arxiv-vanity.com/papers/2008.11239/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-environment-considerations#setting-up-an-environment

Comment: Thanks for info @RobCaplan-MSFT. I was just wondering if Hololens 2 uses IR data (AB map) for SLAM by default? I am asking this as I am not sure if default SLAM in HL2 would benefit from having trackable dots in AB map. I know it is possible to use sensor data in research mode for custom SLAM algorithms, but I would rather stick to default SLAM algorithm provided in HL2. Also I believe it would be quite useful to have an access to all currently tracked feature points. (It is kind of hard to guess how good is actual tracking quality without knowing how many feature points are being tracked.)

Comment: Yes. Research mode exposes the underlying workings to applications. The device itself uses the sensors for its basic operations. The level of information about tracking isn't currently available to apps, even in research mode. You can file feature requests through the feedback hub. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-feedback